# Raspberry pi integration with cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to make access control using firebase and mobile app. Right now my mobile app are saving user data in cloud Firestore. Can my raspberry pi fetch data from cloud Firestore for verification? how can I make this?

Comment: Your raspberry pi is just a computer. You can run code on it, in whatever language you'd like that firebase supports, and that code can access cloud firestore. You could also consider trying out firebase functions, which might also be appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Here's a medium article where someone describes accessing firebase from their raspberry pi. https://medium.com/@dvd.ciri/raspberry-pi-firebase-home-automation-d5a237f18fb5

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a Community Wiki, as this is based on the comments of @jeffkmeng and @Nick.McDermaid:

Your Raspberry PI is just a computer. You can run code on it, in whatever language you'd like and that firebase supports, and that code can access cloud firestore. You could also consider trying out [firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAvvKBBhCXARIsACTePW82t17BPU_WF6WBocaEQ_hg6Fnv_nPakKlGG01oFMEmLLl2VZ-UOegaAtt5EALw_wcB), which might also be appropriate for your use case.

Furthermore you can find an example of how connect to Firestore from a Raspberry PI device in [this article in Medium](https://medium.com/@dvd.ciri/raspberry-pi-firebase-home-automation-d5a237f18fb5).